# Could not convert datetime format using PHP

Tags: php, date

I tried to use `strtotime` function to format the today's date in `PHP` but its giving me the wrong result. My code is given below.

```
<?php
  $today = date("m-d-Y H:i:s");
  echo date('m-d-Y H:i:s', strtotime($today));
?>
```

Here, I am getting this `01-01-1970 05:30:00` result.

Here, I need to get the proper datetime result.

Comment: This is worked for me. <?php
  $today = date("m-d-Y H:i:s");
  echo $today;
?>

Comment: In the manual for strtotime there is a link saying [Valid formats are explained in Date and Time Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

Answer (score 2):

`date("m-d-Y")` is what's causing issues for you. For example, take 01-02-2019 and 02-01-2019 - which is Februrary 1st and which is January 2nd? That format will make `strtotime()` return `false`, as it doesn't know what format that is for days that are greater than 12.

`d-m-Y` would be expected and a valid format.

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` instead. Then you can create a valid DateTime object from that format, and use it however you need it to.

```
$today = DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-Y H:i:s", date("m-d-Y H:i:s"));
echo $today->format("m-d-Y H:i:s");
```

- [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/S67nQ)
- [Documentation for `DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://php.net/datetime.createfromformat)

Alternatively, if you just need to print the date directly and not process it further, you don't need to go through any hoops and can just use `date()` as you were, without the second line. But you can not use that result in a `strtotime()` function, as it will return incorrect results.

```
echo date("m-d-Y H:i:s");
```